# How to debug custom geometry in SceneKit with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, scenekit

I'm trying to learn how to create custom geometry in SceneKit. However, I've tried to make a triangle and it's not showing anything. I'm at a loss as to how to debug this. Is there a way to figure out if the triangle is valid? I just don't know where to start.

For reference, the playground code in question is below. Note that it is written against Swift 4, but the changes between Swift 3 and Swift 4 are so minor that getting it to compile in Swift 3 is trivial.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

let points = [
    SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0),
    SCNVector3Make(0, 10, 0),
    SCNVector3Make(10, 0, 0),
]
let indices = [
    0,2,1,
]

let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: points)
let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .triangles)
let geo = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource], elements: [element])
```

Comment: And you are adding what to what!?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When creating custom `SCNGeometryElement`s the type of the indices needs to be `Int16`<sup>1</sup>. I don't think this documented anywhere. But when you change the declaration of the indices too

```
let indices: [Int16] = [
    0, 2, 1
]
```

the triangle should appear.

---

**Edit**

1: As @mnuages has pointed out, SceneKit supports only 32bit Integers as indices. So you can use `Int8`, `Int16` and `Int32`.

Comment: Wow I would never have guessed this in a million years. Thanks! Oh, and hot tip, you actually can quick look an SCNGeometry in Playgrounds to view it, without having to place it in a scene. Handy!

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation for the Int type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int) we get that

> On 32-bit platforms, Int is the same size as Int32, and on 64-bit platforms, Int is the same size as Int64.

So in a Swift Playground you'll end up with `Int64`.

That's unfortunate because SceneKit (and Metal) only support `UInt8`, `UInt16` and `UInt32`. In the debugger console you should be able to see SceneKit warn about the unsupported 64 bits wide index.

Comment: This answer is correct. Unfortunately there is no warning when using Int64 for indices in Xcode (as of Xcode 9.4)