# SCNGeometry with polygon as primitiveType

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode, scnsphere

Trying to figure out how I create a SCNGeometry with polygon as primitiveType,
My goal is to add polygon shaped node as a child of a sphere node, and make it look like MKPolygon for map kit, [like in this example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87008/overlay-views-mapkit-swift-tutorial).

[image: MKPolygon]

My current code is:

```
//Take an arbitrary array of vectors
let vertices: [SCNVector3] = [
SCNVector3Make(-0.1304485, 0.551937, 0.8236193),
SCNVector3Make(0.01393811, 0.601815, 0.7985139),
SCNVector3Make(0.2971005, 0.5591929, 0.7739732),
SCNVector3Make(0.4516893, 0.5150381, 0.7285002),
SCNVector3Make(0.4629132, 0.4383712, 0.7704169),
SCNVector3Make(0.1333823, 0.5224985, 0.8421428),
SCNVector3Make(-0.1684743, 0.4694716, 0.8667254)]

//Does polygon shape require indices?
let indices: [Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: vertices)
let indexData = Data(bytes: indices, count: indices.count * MemoryLayout<Int>.size)

//Note!!! I get compiler error if primitiveCount is greater than 0
let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData, primitiveType: .polygon, primitiveCount: 0, bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)
let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource], elements: [element])

let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
material.isDoubleSided = true
geometry.firstMaterial = material

let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
```

When using **SCNGeometryElement** like this I get an empty node.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. SceneKit (and Metal) only support 32 bit integers as indices ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44529231/5815048)).
   So the type of your indices array needs to be `[Int32]`.
2. SceneKit needs two pieces of information for polygons: The number of points in the polygon and the index of the point in the vertex array.
   From Apple's documentation on [`SCNGeometryPrimitiveTypePolygon`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometryprimitivetype/scngeometryprimitivetypepolygon?language=objc) (which only exists in Objective-C):

> The element’s data  property holds two sequences of values.
>
> - The first sequence has a number of values equal to the geometry element’s 
>     primitiveCount  value. Each value in this sequence specifies the number of vertices in a polygon primitive. For example, if the first sequence is [5, 3], the geometry element contains a pentagon followed by a triangle.
> - The rest of the data is a sequence of vertex indices. Each entry in the first sequence specifies a corresponding number of entries in the second sequence. For example, if the first sequence includes the values [5, 3], the second sequence includes five indices for the pentagon, followed by three indices for the triangle.

You need to change your index array to:

```
let indices: [Int32] = [7, /* We have a polygon with seven points */,
                        0,1,2,3,4,5,6 /* The seven indices for our polygon */
                       ]
```

Then, set the `primitiveCount` to 1 (we have one polygon to draw) and change the size of the buffer:

```
let indexData = Data(bytes: indices, 
                     count: indices.count * MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)

// Now without runtime error
let element = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData, 
                                 primitiveType: .polygon,
                                 primitiveCount: 1, 
                                 bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size)
```

Comment: Thanks, thats solve most of my problems, on playground though when I assign `primitiveCount: 1` I get an error : `The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.` does that means that I cannot create SCNGeometryElement with polygon as primitiveType on playground?

Comment: I have tested my code in Xcode Playgrounds (although in Xcode 9b2). Try restarting Xcode or copy-paste the code in a new one, this is probably just a bug in Xcode.

Comment: Restart helps, Tnx

Comment: Some polygons are drawn but for some it says "Cannot create buffer of zero length."

Comment: I'm also experiencing what @khunshan is describing, seems to crash more often when many vertices are used. I posted my own question regarding this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773438/creating-a-custom-scngeometry-polygon-plane-with-scngeometryprimitivetype-polygo)