# How to draw curved polygon in ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

need to draw curved polygon in ARScene like on a picture
Using swift code only.
Any ideas ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a curved **Polygonal Model** in `ARKit`/`SceneKit` using several polygons, not single one. For nice curvature 30 to 100 polygons needed.

[image]

But if you meant whether `ARKit`/`SceneKit` supports **NURBS Models** like Maya or 3dsMax does – the answer is NO. You have an API only for Poly Modeling.

For further information please read the [following SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773438/creating-a-custom-scngeometry-polygon-plane-with-scngeometryprimitivetype-polygo/56778785#56778785).